# How can I change the text message on connection request window of metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I want to change the message in connection request window using web3js.
I have attached screenshot here. kindly check it.

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to customize this message.

Comment: Indeed https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/af888d0ab24f1ba5bdbbee807fd769ab37f47741/app/_locales/en/messages.json#L45